# Pause and resume animation in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that has a lottie animation rendered in it.

```
import React from 'react';
import Lottie from 'lottie-react-web';
import { useWindowScroll } from 'react-use';

interface IProps {
  data: string;
}

const Animation: React.FC<IProps> = (props: IProps) => {
  const scroll = useWindowScroll(); // {0, 1280}
  return (
    <Lottie
      isPaused={scroll.y < 1000}
      options={{
        animationData: JSON.parse(props.data),
        loop: false
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default Animation;
```

The animation in the component is supposed to be playing if the window scroll is below a certain pixel. However, it always re-renders the component whenever the scroll position changes, so that the animation will start from the beginning upon every scroll.

I have tried changing the props to

```
interface IProps {
  data: string;
  pause: boolean;
}
```

and then control the state from the parent component

```
import React from 'react';
import { useWindowScroll } from 'react-use';

const Component: React.FC = () => {
const scroll = useWindowScroll();
import data from 'data.json';


return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <Animation
            data={JSON.stringify(data)}
            pause={scroll.y < 1000}
          />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Component;
```

but didn't succeed to pause and resume the animation depending on the scroll position. It always starts from the beginning.

How can I make it work correctly?